# SQLite View extra column with name of table name it grab it from

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a view like this. This view is a combination of many tables. How would I create another column where it's values are the name of the table this view came from ? Thank you in advance.

```
ID      | Name    | #ofCow  | UItem   | place
--------+---------+-------- +---------+----------
0       | Bob      | 7       | 1      | maine
1       | Bob      | 3       | 5      | new york
2       | Tom      | 2       | 5      | cali
```

Comment: Its a simple select * from table a union select * from table b;

Comment: You could try `SELECT *,'tablea' FROM table a UNION SELECT *,'tableb' FROM...`